# Does combat while swimming affect anything other than movement?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, combat

Does combat while swimming affect anything other than movement speed?

I assume that melee/ranged combat is affected if a PC is underwater after failing a swim check or choosing to dive?

Do these effects have a different impact to creatures with a swim ability e.g. Reefclaw?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combat in aquatic terrain also affects attack rolls and damage as well as other things in a very complex way.  The online Pathfinder SRD [has an entire section dedicated to the rules on it](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/wilderness/terrain/aquatic-terrain) that answers all your questions (what about with a swim speed, etc.).